# Get Repeater Label in the current "row" being accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, repeater

I have the following Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptLeaveRequests" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound"> <ItemTemplate>
<table id="tableItem" runat="server">
    <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblHours" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Hours") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 200px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPeriod" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AMorPM") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 200px; font-size:10px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Note") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="50px">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtVerified" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the data in each Label (ex: ***Convert.ToString((Label)item.FindControl("Date"))*** ) but it is returning an empty string, what am I doing wrong:

```
 foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptLeaveRequests.Items)
            {
                var rdbList = item.FindControl("rbtVerified") as RadioButtonList;
                switch (rdbList.SelectedValue)
                {
                    case "1":
                        if (new LeaveLogic().AddLeaveEmployee(Convert.ToString((Label)item.FindControl("Date")), Convert.ToDouble((Label)item.FindControl("Hours")), Convert.ToString((Label)item.FindControl("AMorPM")), "Vacational Leave", Convert.ToInt32(Context.User.Identity.Name), Convert.ToString((Label)item.FindControl("Note")))
                        {
                            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
                        }
                        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not working because you aren't finding the controls. `FindControl` will return null if it can't find the control, and `Convert.ToString` will return an empty string if the object value is null.

From what I can see, you are searching for the wrong string ID. So instead of `Date`, it should be `lblDate`.

If you are in debug build mode, keep in mind that ASP.NET loves to change your control names at runtime, so "lblDate" control might not actually be "lblDate". So you can try debugging on the browser and inspect your elements' IDs for their actual IDs.

Also, you probably want to do this instead if you want the label's actual data (notice the `.Text`):

```
((Label)item.FindControl("lblDate")).Text
```

Comment: Just an update, I just realized you really don't need Convert.ToString if you are accessing the Text property of the label, so I updated that code line.